# How to prevent 404 when a slash is added to url that includes a file extension on Windows Server

Tags: iis

I noticed a lot of 404s in my logs which are seemingly being caused by an app/device automatically adding a slash to urls like http://example.com/folder/page.asp

So the url ends up looking like http://example.com/folder/page.asp/ which causes an error and 404 response.

This is on Windows Server 2019 running IIS.

I tried using UrlRewrite using code I found for a similar problem, but it doesn't change anything at all.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)/$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Enable FRT and see what happens under the hood, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: What I want to know is what form of URL are you accessing in your browser? `folder/page.asp`? Or `folder/page.asp/` ? If you are requesting `folder/page.asp`, it will not trigger the rule. This rule only matches those that end with `/`, so if you request `folder/page.asp/` you will be redirected to `folder/page.asp`.

Comment: The link is folder/page.asp and any links pointing to it are folder/page.asp but I see lots of 404s recorded for folder/page.asp/ so some app/device is adding that / to the end. Even after adding that rewrite rule when I use folder/page.asp/ in a browser it still gives a 404, so that rule, as it is, is not removing the trailing slash and redirecting to folder/page.asp

Comment: As suggested by Lex Li, you need to enable failed request tracing for your website, find the corresponding xml file in the FailedReqLogFiles folder, open it and see the cause of the problem.